# change odd elements in list to negative

Tags: python

I am trying to change odd elements in a list of int to negative using slicing

```
l[1::2] = -1 * l[1::2]
```

However, I encounter the following error:

```
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 2
```

Comment: When you say "odd elements", do you mean elements at odd indices in the list?

Comment: yes so like i[1], i[3], i[5]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to uses slices:

```
>>> a = [1,4,7,8,2]
>>> a[1::2] = [-x for x in a[1::2]]
>>> a
[1, -4, 7, -8, 2]
```

When assigning to an extended slice like `a[1::2]`, the list/slice on the right hand side must be the same length as the left hand side. In the above, we've mapped to `a[1::2]` with a list comprehension, so the length is unchanged. If we consider `-1 * a[1::2]` this yields `[]` which is of a different length.

Answer (score -1):

Best way would be to do it vectorized with numpy. Without numpy, I don't see a way to do it without creating a new loop. Here you have two examples of how to do it. With and without numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

# vectorized
a = np.arange(10)
a[1::2] *= -1
print(a)
# >>> [ 0  -1 2  -3 4  -5 6  -7 8  -9]

a = [i for i in range(10)]
a = [i if i%2==0 else i*-1 for i in a] # need to loop through list again..
print(a)
# >>> [0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, -9]
```

Edited to fix odd elements to negative, not pos.

Comment: _Without numpy, I don't see a way to do it without creating a new loop._ I strongly suggest seeing the other answers to this question and perhaps revising that statement.

Comment: @Chris The other answers and Stein's non-NumPy version *do* all loop, via list comprehensions. Technically the NumPy version loops too of course, but at the C level instead of in Python. (Though Steinn, I think you meant to check modulo of the *index*, not the value.)